# Wordpress how to load posts into separate div when each featured image is clicked?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Hi im pulling featured images and displaying them. I am trying to set it to load the post that the featured image is part of into another div when the image is clicked. As i have more than one image i need some way of clearing it when any other images are clicked. I could do this with jQuery toggle but i think it might not be the best thing to page load times. Any other options i could look at would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You  may have found a solution to this but I had a similar problem, I had a menu with thumbnails showing on hover and certain menus were to be present for certain posts. I solved it by putting my php for the menu and thumbnails in the widget area and set up some sidget contexts accordingly. http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-context/